# Multiple bidirectional mapping issue on JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I've been having issues figuring out JPA OneToMany/ManyToOne's mapping, I was told initially that it had to do with CascateType.ALL needing to be in the parent entity, I did add that and I was still getting a "detached entity" error, I changed the fetch types and now I'm getting a

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :
```

Error, I am completely lost on what to do.

I have a main entity (reserve) that contains a OneToOne relationship, and two OneToMany relationships.

The OneToMany relationships have this as annotations:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "reserve", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

The children (for example one of them) has two ManyTwoOne relationships as well with the annotations being:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idReserve", referencedColumnName = "idReserve")
```

Here is the creation process (the actual entity names/attributes are in spanish, I just translated it above for easier understanding):

```
Pago pago = new Pago();
        pago.setTipo("Efectivo");
        pago.setTotal(1500);

        Alojamiento alojamiento = new Alojamiento();
        alojamiento.setNombre("Hotel las Flores");
        alojamiento.setNumeroDeHabitaciones(30);
        alojamiento.setTipo("Hotel Turistico");
        alojamiento.setValoracion(5);
        alojamiento.setUbigeo(11);
        alojamiento.setCodAlojamiento("ALO01");

        Habitacion habitacion = new Habitacion();
        habitacion.setDescripcion("Habitación Ejecutiva");
        habitacion.setTipo(3);
        habitacion.setNumero("5");
        habitacion.setPrecio("1500 dolares");
        habitacion.setCodHabitacion("HAB01");

        List<Habitacion> listHab = new ArrayList<>();
        listHab.add(habitacion);
        alojamiento.setHabitaciones(listHab);

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setNombres("Jeremy");
        usuario.setApellidos("Tornero");
        usuario.setContrasena("1234");
        usuario.setEmail("jeremy@gmail.com");
        usuario.setFoto("");
        usuario.setCodUsuario("USU01");

        Reserva reserva = new Reserva();
        reserva.setCantidadDePersonas(3);
        reserva.setFechaIngreso(LocalDate.of(19,7,15));
        reserva.setFechaSalida(LocalDate.of(19,10,30));
        reserva.setComentarios("");
        List<Habitacion> listHab2 = new ArrayList<>();
        listHab2.add(habitacion);
        reserva.setHabitaciones(listHab2);
        reserva.setUsuario(usuario);
        List<Pago> listPago = new ArrayList<>();
        listPago.add(pago);
        reserva.setPagos(listPago);

        pago.setReserva(reserva);
        habitacion.setAlojamiento(alojamiento);
        habitacion.setReserva(reserva);
        usuario.setReserva(reserva);

        pagoRepository.save(pago);
        log.info("success saving pago");
        habitacionRepository.save(habitacion);
        log.info("success saving habitacion");
        alojamientoRepository.save(alojamiento);
        log.info("success saving alojamiento");
        usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
        log.info("success saving usuario");
        reservaRepository.save(reserva);
        log.info("success saving reserva");
```

I seem to be getting the errors when debugging when it's time to call the save() method from the repository (at the end). I'm not entirely sure if it's caused by entity mapping, how I am mapping, fetch, cascade or if it's due to how I'm creating them in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it fixed after a few hours, apparently the issue was the order in which I was adding them, the classes with OneToMany should be instantiated first and not assigned anything, instead you just save it directly, then when the ManyToOne classes are created, you assign them the already saved OneToMany class, and then .save with the repository class, that way it will have their ids correctly assigned for the json/database